# Unable to load a video in the modal

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

```
<div className="modal fade in" id="HelpVideo">
                <div className="modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                       <div className="modal-body">
                            <iframe width="100%" height="350" src="https://vimeo.com/273326561" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am using the above modal, in the modal i am trying to use Iframe but I am getting `Refused to display 'https://vimeo.com/273326561' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```html
<div className="modal fade in" id="HelpVideo">
                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                           <div className="modal-body">
                                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/273326561" width="100%" height="350" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I went to your video, hit share, then copy and pasted to embed code, then customized it to your dimensions